# Get user given jwt Knock Rails JWT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

I use [Knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) in Rails to authenticate users using JWT.

I get authentication out of the box, but there are cases where I need to **get the user object when I have the jwt**. So how do I do this using some function built inside of Knock

```
get_user(jwt)               # should return user if valid or null if not
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't require `Knock`, this can be easily done with `ruby-jwt` gem which Knock also uses

```
def get_user(jwt)
    decoded_token = JWT.decode jwt, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base, true, { :algorithm => 'HS256' }
    current_user = User.find((decoded_token[0])['sub']))
    current_user
end
```